# Same instructions with different cpu cycles

Tags: c++, performance, intel, avx, instructions

I'm tuning an c++ program, two different inputs lead to almost the same number or instructions, however there is a grate difference between cpu cycles.

Below are `perf stat` info, that is really weird. Does some one know what may leads to such a time difference?

Performance counter stats for `./sai2 100000,C,98.700,60,98.695,0.2,0.0`:

```
   2684.371940      task-clock (msec)         #    1.000 CPUs utilized          
            17      context-switches          #    0.006 K/sec                  
             1      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
           921      page-faults               #    0.343 K/sec                  
 7,292,413,665      cycles                    #    2.717 GHz                    
11,267,827,416      instructions              #    1.55  insn per cycle         
   940,483,779      branches                  #  350.355 M/sec                  
       132,437      branch-misses             #    0.01% of all branches        

   2.685433574 seconds time elapsed
```

Performance counter stats for `./sai2 100000,P,98.700,60,98.695,0.2,0.0`

```
  25698.831411      task-clock (msec)         #    1.000 CPUs utilized          
            72      context-switches          #    0.003 K/sec                  
            19      cpu-migrations            #    0.001 K/sec                  
           921      page-faults               #    0.036 K/sec                  
70,402,935,601      cycles                    #    2.740 GHz                    
10,418,026,021      instructions              #    0.15  insn per cycle         
   956,483,724      branches                  #   37.219 M/sec                  
       323,444      branch-misses             #    0.03% of all branches        

  25.702346518 seconds time elapsed
```

What really confused me is that the most time cost code are almost same.

```
// const double vector definitions
__m256d vec_1_p = _mm256_set1_pd(v_1_p_discount);
__m256d vec_p = _mm256_set1_pd(v_p_discount);
__m256d vec_tricky = _mm256_set_pd(tricky_3, tricky_2, tricky, 1);
__m256d vec_strike = _mm256_set1_pd(strike);

for (int m = m_stepNumber - 1; m > 0; m--) {
  double m_s_pointer = power_d / d;
  power_d = m_s_pointer;
  for (int n = 0; n < m; n += 4) {
    double *val = known + n;
    double *dest = to_calc + n;

    __m256d hold_0 = _mm256_load_pd(val);
    __m256d hold_1 = _mm256_loadu_pd(val+1);
    hold_0 = _mm256_mul_pd(hold_0, vec_1_p);
    hold_1 = _mm256_mul_pd(hold_1, vec_p);
    hold_0 = _mm256_add_pd(hold_0, hold_1);

    __m256d vec_tmp = _mm256_set1_pd(m_s_pointer);
    vec_tmp = _mm256_mul_pd(vec_tmp, vec_tricky);

    //vec_tmp = _mm256_sub_pd(vec_tmp, vec_strike);   this run in quick case
    //vec_tmp = _mm256_sub_pd(vec_strike, vec_tmp);   this run in slow case

    hold_0 = _mm256_max_pd(hold_0, vec_tmp);
    _mm256_store_pd(dest, hold_0);
    m_s_pointer *= tricky_4;
  }
  std::swap(known, to_calc);
}
```

I have use `perf record` to see the hotpot of the slower case as below

```
    0.00 │520:┌─→vmulpd -0x8(%rdx),%ymm1,%ymm3
   41.48 │    │  add    $0x4,%ecx
    1.94 │    │  add    $0x20,%rdx
    0.52 │    │  vmovup -0x20(%rdx),%ymm0
    3.85 │    │  add    $0x20,%rsi
    0.31 │    │  vfmadd %ymm2,%ymm3,%ymm0
   42.73 │    │  vmovup -0x20(%rsi),%ymm3
    5.53 │    │  vmaxpd %ymm3,%ymm0,%ymm0
    2.77 │    │  vmovap %ymm0,-0x28(%rdx)
    0.86 │    │  cmp    %edi,%ecx 
         │    └──jle    520
```

the faster case

```
      3.43 │398:┌─→vmovup -0x8(%rdx),%ymm3
      9.18 │    │  add    $0x4,%ecx
      1.64 │    │  add    $0x20,%rdx
      5.44 │    │  vmovup -0x20(%rdx),%ymm0
     12.03 │    │  add    $0x20,%rsi
      2.32 │    │  vmulpd %ymm1,%ymm3,%ymm3
      7.28 │    │  vfmadd %ymm2,%ymm3,%ymm0
     16.77 │    │  vmovup -0x20(%rsi),%ymm3
     19.33 │    │  vmaxpd %ymm3,%ymm0,%ymm0
     15.83 │    │  vmovup %ymm0,-0x28(%rdx)
      6.70 │    │  cmp    %edi,%ecx
           │    └──jle    398
```

Comment: Are these results reproducible? Looks like the second run has lots of context switches and cpu-migrations, was something else running in the background?

Comment: the second run also has a significantly higher number of branch-misses, which can also impact performance (although I doubt that alone would cause the major performance loss, especially since in absolute terms, neither amount of misses is very high).

Comment: Generally, single program runs are unlikely to deliver reliable measurements (unless perhaps on a micro-controller where nothing else runs; but even there, interrupts can have impact on run-time...). If some higher prioritised process started in between the two runs, it might just have "stolen" CPU time during the second run as well (additionally to causing the higher number of context switches).

Comment: The result is reproducible, I use a physical & a vm to run many times. The argument 100000 can be used to increase algorithm complexity, and the latter is always slower .

Comment: The only difference is the calculated value stored in arrays, I counted the times in the inner for-loop, and the times are almost the same.

Comment: What is `vec_strike` ? Where does it come from?

Comment: `vec_strike` are const double vector.

Comment: on intel site there is latency and other stuff for each . Better check on msvc perf explorer , stuff you'd post looks not serious

Comment: @Sai the reason I asked is because I was wondering if it was to do with cache misses, so I wondered where it was on the heap/stack. But I think it is not, I think it is all about branch predictions.

Comment: First operand of `_mm256_sub_pd` is always a register. second operand can be a register or a memory location. Maybe that causes registers to be allocated differently in the two versions? Have you looked at the generated assembler?

Comment: I show the info of `perf record` and see the hotpot is `vmovup -0x20(%rsi),%ymm3`, but I couldn't undersand the reason.

Comment: @AlanBirtles: those context-switch numbers look pretty normal considering that the 2nd one ran for 10x more time.

Comment: Normally cache-miss loads show up in `perf record` as more time on the instructions that consume the load results, rather than on the load itself, but that would be one obvious explanation for very low ILP in a similar loop.  Both versions asm versions have no loop-carried dependency chain through the vector instructions: they load new data every time and store a result.  Is it possible that the output array is an exact multiple of 4kiB away from one of the inputs, creating false memory dependencies?

Comment: You should share a full MVCE and see if others can reproduce it. Otherwise you'll only get guesses.